# Why is counting unique concatenated keys returning 1 instead of 0?

Tags: postgresql, concatenation, coalesce, unique-key

I am trying to count the total number of price quotes we've done for a customer which I have. Just counting all the price quote IDs in our customer price quote (cpq) table.

`COUNT(DISTINCT cpq.id) AS "Total Number of Quotes",`

As expected, that returns many zeroes. I.e., we have customer accounts created that have not had any price quotes. And many non-zeroes.

In the same table, I have origin city and destination city. I am trying to concatenate these two fields and then count the number of unique origin/destination combinations. Originally I tried this:

`COUNT(DISTINCT(concat(cpq.origin_city_id, cpq.dest_city_id))) as "Number of Unique Routes Quoted",`

and for the customers that had price quote activity, it worked. But for customers that did not have any quotes, this returned a 1, which is nonsensical. I.e., if the customer does not have any quote activity (quotes = 0), then that customer wouldn't appear in the customer_price_quotes table and thus, the number of unique routes quoted should not be 1. Basically, if total number of quotes = 0, then number of unique routes quoted should = 0. I tried coalesce but the number of unique routes quoted was much less than it should have been.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(CONCAT(NULL,NULL)) = 1
```

This is because CONCAT(NULL,NULL) does not equal null, so you're basically providing COUNT with a single value regardless of the data in the table.  Try the following:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT(cpq.origin_city_id, cpq.dest_city_id))
```

You'll also need a where clause:

```
WHERE cpq.origin_city_id IS NOT NULL AND cpq.dest_city_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: If he adds that to the where clause, he might get the wrong answer for the other aggregate he described, `COUNT(DISTINCT cpq.id)`.  So he should add it to a filter clause instead.  `COUNT(DISTINCT(cpq.origin_city_id, cpq.dest_city_id)) filter (where cpq.origin_city_id is not null or cpq.dest_city_id is not null)`